# Javascript - Detecting chinese character input like Google docs

Tags: javascript, gwt, input, user-input, cjk

I'm trying to reliably detect when chinese characters are inserted into a text box. If I add keyup, keydown, and keypress handlers to an input field, no event is fired when the user selects a chinese character from an IME (input method editor).  For example, on Mac/Firefox with Chinese simplified pinyan if I type:

ni then hit 1

I only receive the keydown event for 'n' and the key up for '1'.  No keypress event is fired.  Note: I'm using GWT but I don't think it should matter.

I was curious how Google docs does this.  I noticed specifically for Chinese, the 'n' character appended as text to a hidden iframe with the class "docs-texteventtarget-iframe" (but not the 'i').  I would imagine they're doing this to detect when a chinese character is inserted.

How does Google docs know that the input language changed to chinese? For instance, if my input language is English and I type 'n', it is not appended to that hidden iframe.  Is there any common techniques to detecting chinese character key events?

Comment: Did you try adding a change handler?

Answer (score 2):

When the user inputs text using an IME (Input Method Editor), then before the content of the input field changes, there is a lot of interaction going on within the IME composition window. You can detect this through the `compositionstart` and `compositionend` events. In fact, while composition is in progress, you definitely do *not* want to steal the keyup/keydows events from the IME. On a text input element you can then catch when the content changes through the `input` event.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that you are not getting a keypress event because the input is coming from an IME instead of the keyboard, just as you don't get key events if you paste into a field.

You can try adding a [ValueChangeHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ValueChangeHandler.html) to the textbox to see if that catches the events that you are looking for.